# Haskell Type error in application

Tags: haskell

i keep getting type error in application in this line : filter1 (k) (y:ys) = if occursIn (headof (y:ys))(k) then filter1 k (ys) else filter1 k1 (ys) where k1 = k:y 
any help please , 
thanks in advance

```
occursIn (x) [] = False

occursIn x (x1:xs) = if (x == x1) then True else occursIn x (xs)

headof [] = error "empty list"

headof (x:xs) = x

filter1 (k) [] = k

filter1 (k) (y:ys) = if occursIn (headof (y:ys))(k) then filter1 k (ys) else filter1 k1 (ys) where k1 = k:y


filter [] = []
filter (x:xs) = if xs == [] then x else filter1 [] (x:xs)
```

Comment: What's the error you get? What are the expected types of `filter1` and `filter`?

Comment: @acomar, nothing wrong with practicing.  Please don't call newcomers' code "poor".

Comment: To suggest how to fix your problem, we first need to know what those functions' behaviors are supposed to be.

Comment: i am just trying to remove the duplicates from a given list using filter which calls a helper method filter1 which takes two lists , the first list is an accumulator that keeps adding distinct elements from the second argument so for example if i have [1,2,4,2,3,1] i want it to be [1,2,4,3]

Comment: Type error in application
*** Expression     : occursIn (headof (y : ys)) l
*** Term           : headof (y : ys)
*** Type           : [a]
*** Does not match : a
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type
and this is the error i'm getting

Comment: @luqui: My comment reads much worse than I intended on a reread. I meant that it looked similar to `elem` but obviously didn't function. I meant to ask for clarification, not criticize.

Comment: @acomar it's okay no need to explain i wasn't offended i know you're trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

`a : b` is the *element* `a` prepended to the *list* `b`.  In `where k1 = k:y` it looks like you have that backwards.

In

```
filter (x:xs) = if xs == [] then x else filter1 [] (x:xs)
```

the `then` case, `x`, should be returning a list (because all the other cases return lists), but is instead returning just an element.  Perhaps you meant `[x]`?

I would recommend renaming `filter` to something else, since `filter` is already the name of a function in the standard library, and you will get "ambiguous occurence" errors when you try to use it.

Now might be a good time to start experimenting with type signatures.  When I intend to write a function, I usually write the type signature first, and consult it while I write the function's body. It helps with small errors like these, and it will also improve the error messages the compiler gives you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for helping , i know it looks poor but i am still a beginner in haskell , any tips for practicing type signatures? , thanks again,,

Comment: @user3576750, of course, beginners welcome! :-)  One good tip is that in `ghci`, you can use `:t` to look at the inferred type of something.  Try `:t headof` after loading your program in `ghci`.  It'll give you `[a] -> a`, which means it takes a list of some type and returns something of that type (lowercase names are variables in types).  You can then say `headof :: [a] -> a` in your source code.  Play with this idea, see if you can understand the types.  Next try writing a type signature for a function without ghci's help and see if it compiles.  Etc.